# ¿Cómo realizar esta consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estaba realizando este problema en LeetCode en el lenguaje MySQL:
https://leetcode.com/problems/combine-two-tables/

Lo resolví con el siguiente código:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CITY, STATE 
FROM PERSON 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON PERSON.PERSONID=ADDRESS.PERSONID
```

Y su output es el siguiente:

```
 {"headers": ["FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "CITY", "STATE"], "values": [["Allen", "Wang", null, null]]}
```

La plataforma me lo aceptó, pero me surge una duda: ¿Como realizar una consulta que no devuelva el tercer y cuarto valor, correspondientes a ciudad y estado, como null, sino que devuelve sus valores correspondientes de la segunda tabla?

Las tablas son:

```
Table Person
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| PersonId    | int     |
| FirstName   | varchar |
| LastName    | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
PersonId is the primary key column for this table.

Table: Address
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| AddressId   | int     |
| PersonId    | int     |
| City        | varchar |
| State       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
AddressId is the primary key column for this table.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que lo primero es tener claro lo que significa `LEFT JOIN>` en la instrucción SQL. Con `LEFT JOIN` obtienes todos los registros de la tabla a la izquierda (`PERSON`) y los registros que tengan coincidencias de la tabla a la derecha (`ADDRESS`), el resultado `NULL` indica que no hay coincidencias.

Las coincidencias son determinadas por la expresión lógica que le sigue al `ON` (`PERSON.PERSONID=ADDRESS.PERSONID`)

En este caso en particular, la consulta se puede leer de la siguiente manera:

> *Selecciona todos los registros de la tabla `PERSON` sin importar si tienen o no tienen dirección asociada en la tabla `ADDRESS`*

El resultado que obtienes, es porque el único registro de la tabla `PERSON` no tiene dirección registrada en la tabla `ADDRESS`.

Lo recomendable es que crees un conjunto de datos con más casos donde tengas
registros en la tabla `PERSONS` sin dirección en la tabla `ADDRESS`, con una y con más de una dirección y ejecutes la consulta para que puedas mejorar la comprensión del caso.

Por otra parte, si el enunciado de la pregunta en [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/combine-two-tables/) pidiera todos los registros en la tabla `PERSONS` que tengan al menos una dirección en la tabla `ADDRESS`, en lugar de `LEFT JOIN` tendrías que utilizar `INNER JOIN`.

Con `INNER JOIN` obtienes solamente los registros que tienen coincidencias en las dos tablas.

Ver ejemplos de [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx/)
Ver ejemplos de [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx/)